# Docker for Mac Host Networking

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm using Docker for Mac. I have two containers.

1st: A PHP application that is attempting to connect to localhost:3306 to MySQL.

2nd: MySQL

When running with links, they are able to reach each other.

However, I would like to avoid changing any of the code in the PHP application (e.g. changing localhost to "mysql") and stay with using localhost.

Host networking seems to do the trick, the problem is, when I enable host networking I can't access the PHP application on port 80 on my host mac.

If I docker exec -it into the php application and curl localhost, i see the HTML, so it looks like the port is just not forwarding to the host machine?

Comment: could you post your docker command? use docker run -p localport:docker-port to forward the ports - take a look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

Comment: @lumos0815 i'm using docker compose, but for your example try enabling host networking and  see if you can access that port from your host

Answer (score 0):

this is an example for docker-compose 
it runs mysql in one container and phpmyadmin in another
the containers are linked together
you can access the containers via your host machine on the ports
3316 and 8889

```
my_mysql:
  image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
  container_name: my_mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
  ports:
    - 3316:3306
  restart: always

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: my_myadmin
    links:
     - my_mysql:my_mysql
    environment:
     - PMA_ARBITRARY=0
     - PMA_HOST=my_mysql
    ports:
     - 8889:80
    restart: always
```

Comment: In this example, it is using bridge networking, my issue is when host networking is enabled. Can you give that a try?